# How do I make a desktop shortcut for rdesktop?

Tags: debian, raspbian-stretch, rdp

I want know how to make a shortcut for rdesktop, the remote desktop client?

I installed it with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install rdesktop
```

I searched in the path `/usr/share/applications/` but I see any resktop.desktop

Can you help to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new text file called `rdesktop.desktop` in the `/home/pi/Desktop/` directory, e.g. `/home/pi/Desktop/rdesktop.desktop`

## It should contain the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=rdesktop
Comment=RDesktop Shortcut
Icon=/path/to/a/icon/for/the/rdesktop/shortcut
Exec=/usr/share/applications/rdesktop
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=false
Categories=None;
```

## Explination:

- Name – The name you want displayed
- Comment – Your comment
- Icon – A file to use for the icon.  Your own or have a look in the `/usr/share/pixmaps/` directory for something suitable.
- Exec – The executable (can include sudo if your executable uses the IO). Can be the name of an executable program, or more complex, e.g. `Exec=lxterminal –command "less /root/README.TXT"`

## Requested Update:

for other keyboard letters (eg. è,é,etc...), get a virtual (onscreen) keyboard:
First thing to do:

- Open terminal

Second you will need to update your repositories:

- `sudo apt-get update`

An upgrade to the whole system isn't needed but it is recommended:

- `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Now we can install the virtual keyboard (matchbox):

- `sudo apt-get install matchbox-keyboard`

Rebooting is recommended:

- `sudo reboot`

Now you can access the keyboard:

MENU >> ACCESSORIES >> KEYBOARD

[image: Access the keyboard]
<sub>(source: [modmypi.com](https://www.modmypi.com/image/data/tutorials/matchbox-keyboard/matchbox-2.JPG))</sub>

If the keyboard isn't visible in the menu you can enable it by going to:

MENU >> PREFERENCES >> Main Menu Editor

There you will be able to enable the keyboard.

If everything has gone perfectly you will now have an onscreen keyboard.

[image: Onscreen keyboard]
<sub>(source: [modmypi.com](https://www.modmypi.com/image/data/tutorials/matchbox-keyboard/matchbox-3.JPG))</sub>

Comment: This is work fine. But I have some problem with the string who have accent like (è, é) the keyboard isn't at the good language. How can I fix that. I use a belgium keyboard.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean

Comment: With rdesktop the keyboard (french belgium) don't work. The character like é or à or again è, don't work. I have this : é => e, è => e and à => a. How can I fix that and make the prominents characters work ? (It's when I connected to the Windows Server 2008 R2)